# Differentiate Crashes that occur on 2 devices with same Model and same Version in Firebash Crashlytics

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I am using Firebase Crashlytics to check for the Crash Occurences, but I got stuck when i crash tested with 2 devices having same Model and same version.
I am not getting list of crashes seperately,rather in a same list
For Example) If DevA showing 5 Error and DevB showing 3 Errors, All 8 appeared on same list.

I tried Android's Build ID to send as customkey to Firebase Crashlytics Console to differentiate the crash occurance on each device seperately

```
  android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        Log.i("android_id", android_id);
        crashlytics.setCustomKey("deviceID", android_id);
```

But,I see alot of peers shared that buildID may be change or similar sometime,when we do factory reset.